# The other night I did these things

Tags: lateral-thinking, knowledge

The other night I did these things:

1. I alternately climbed the rungs of success and slid down to failure.
2. I got a car, went to college, got married and had up to four strangely-colored children
3. I went to jail, got out and bought up a good chunk of New Jersey.
4. I was jocundly rewarded for using anomalistic words.
5. I tried to conquer the world utilizing limited travel corridors.

> Can you tell me what night it was?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sounds like every night at my house, aka

> Game night. Each line hints at a board game: CHUTES AND LADDERS, LIFE, MONOPOLY, SCRABBLE, and RISK.